# cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener in android

Tags: android, gps, android-permissions, android-gps, locationlistener

I am trying access GPS in my application.
I have given the permission but still getting error.

If I will import instead of **import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener** to **import android.location.LocationListener;**

and

mLocService.requestLocationUpdates(mLocProvider.getName(), getGpsUpdatePeriod(prefs), getGpsDistanceUpdatePeriod(prefs), (android.location.LocationListener) this);

code is comping but it not in entering into if() condition and "gps permission--->2" not getting in log.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;


public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity implements ObdProgressListener, LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gpsStart();
}

 private synchronized void gpsStart() {
    if (!mGpsIsStarted && mLocProvider != null && mLocService != null && mLocService.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps permission--->1");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
           Log.d(TAG, "gps permission--->2");
            mLocService.requestLocationUpdates(mLocProvider.getName(), getGpsUpdatePeriod(prefs), getGpsDistanceUpdatePeriod(prefs), (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
            mGpsIsStarted = true;
            return;
        }
 } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps permission--->3");
        gpsStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.status_gps_no_support));
    }
}
```

getting **Cast 4th parameter to 'android.location.LocationListener'** in android.

If I give like below ,

mLocService.requestLocationUpdates(mLocProvider.getName(), getGpsUpdatePeriod(prefs), getGpsDistanceUpdatePeriod(prefs), (android.location.LocationListener) this);

getting error ** cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener**

Comment: show more code and put more detailed problem description. there is no question in fact currently... do you have `implements LocationListener` in your class?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure , I will do.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `requestLocationUpdates()` expects a `android.location.LocationListener` as 4th parameter, but you are passing it a `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` which, although it has the same name (except for the package) is a completely different class.

So basically, its like passing an Integer when a String is expected.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ridcully. exactly it is expecting "android.location.LocationListener", when I this argument it not entering into to the permission if() condition. I have seen some answers in stack over flow we have to give "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener" is it correct ?